# How to set rules in compton

Tags: libreoffice, transparency, compton

I have found *really* different configs of `compton` in the internets, and I just don't understand which part of them is up to date.
I tried to make compton use those config files (or their mashed up parts) with no success, and survived until now with just `compton -bcCGf -i 0.8 -e 0.8` in autostart. But working with 2 documents or a browser in background became such pain that I went to RTFM (`compton --help`) and found `--opacity-rule` argument, which is a great relief.  Now I have `compton -bcCGf -i 0.8 -e 0.8 --opacity-rule '99:name *= "Chromium" && name *= "LibreOffice"'`

Question: how do I express not window title masks, but rather window type?  Or are Libreoffice menus somehow distinguashebly titled?
From those I saw in compton.c, I'd exclude "toolbar",
  "menu",
  "splash",
  "dropdown_menu",
  "popup_menu",
  "tooltip",
  "notify",
"utility", however not sure about latter.
Better in arguments to compton, but if that's smh impossible, pls do give an example of working config. Saw this in one config, btw: `opacity-rule = ["99:class_g = 'gimp' && window_type = 'tooltip' && window_type = 'toolbox'"];`
Can someone maybe *convert* it to relevant compton arguments, or at least convert the config line itself

Comment: 1) have you looked at # https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/master/man/compton.1.asciidoc#format-of-conditions ? 2) Also, check out [compton's issues](https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues) where you can ask your own question; 3) I remember issues about aspects of LibreOffice being difficult possibly because of non-standard nomenclature.

Comment: @DKBose this readme seems to confirm that modifying window type rules is **only** possible from config. Can you suggest how to write config based on my parameters? How to change that default one in compton.sample.conf? I mean, those arguments in readme on github and in `--help` are useful... But what about their config analogues?
Small addition - all I need is everything enabled except transparency on chromium/LO/LO dropdown menus, so that shouldn't be har, right? :)

Comment: I searched the 'net for "sample compton config files" and found https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304138&p=13396230#post13396230 which has a compton.conf with some explanation.